# Changing and updating variables between classes in pyqt

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt

I need to change the value of two variables between two classes, and continuosly be updating them after every change.

This is the code:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):

  varA = None
  varB = None

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here to create a matplotlib figure

    self.linedit = LineEdit(self)  #Added while editing

    self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.A)
    self.figure_canvas.mpl_connect("button_release_event", self.B)

  def A(self, event):
    varA = event.xdata
    #I need to change from here the value of variable1 in class 'LineEdit' 

  self.linedit.variable1 = LineEdit.varA  #Added while editing

  def B(self, event(:
    varB = event.xdata
    #I need to change from here the value of variable2 in class 'LineEdit'

    self.linedit.variable2 = LineEdit.varB  #Added while editing

class LineEdit(QDialog):
  variable1 = None
  variable2 = None

  def __init__(self, parent):
    QDialog.__init__(self, None)
    #I open a QDialog.ui file which have 2 QLineEdit

  def C(self):
    #Here i need to change the value of variable1 and variable2 and update those value
    #so i can show them

    self.lineEdit.setText(str(self.variable1))
    self.lineEdit2.setText(str(self.variable2))
```

What I am trying to do is to save the coords of the mouse when I click it and when I release the button. After doing this, the saved coords must be shown in each of the `QLineEdit` in the  `ui` file.

How can I accomplish this? Is there another way to do this?

Hope you can help me.

### EDIT

I added the lines with the advices you gave me. I tried this before but it does not work, i mean that it does not change the value when i click in the matplotlib figure.

Comment: You need to create a `LineEdit` instance within `Window.__init__()`. `self.lineedit = LineEdit(parent)`. Then from within `Window.A` you can call `self.lineedit.variable1 = varA` and similar for for `Window.B`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and I get an error that says: `NameError: global name "parent" is not defined`. What am I missing?

Comment: I was just using `parent` as a place holder. You'll want to pass the *actual* parent (probably `self.lineedit = LineEdit(self)`)

Comment: Sorry, i mean that I tried this before using `self` and nothing happened. And when i read your answer I wrote `parent ` by mistake.

Comment: Can you update the post to include that?

Comment: Is the LineEdit dialog a child of the MainWindow?  How are these being created?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, i had some problems with mi pc. I added the lines that @Suever told me. I do not know if I made a mistake. Hope you can help me, and thank you for your answers.